# How to import the Contract type from the web3.js library?

Tags: web3js, frontend, typescript

Here's how I can do that in ethers@4.0.47:

```
import { Contract, ethers } from "ethers";

const contractInstance: Contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi);
```

But in web3.js@1.2.8 none of the following works:

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import { Contract } from "web3"; // option 1
import { Contract } from "web3/types"; // option 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
import { Contract } from "web3-eth-contract";
```

It's recommended that you also list `web3-eth-contract` as a direct dependency so you avoid getting a warning from eslint.

Answer (score -2):

```
import { Contract, utils } from "ethers";
const poolAbi = require("./abis/pool.json");
const pool = new Contract(POOL_ADDRESS, poolAbi, signer);

// repay amount of DAI debt using aDAI tokens
pool.repayWithATokens(DAI.address, amount, 2);

// User must hold aDAI >= amount being repaid
```

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to do? Where should we get the file `pool.json`? What's `POOL_ADDRESS `?